# Question about a "sort of" skew symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

it has main diag elements = 0, non-zero off diag elements like A12 = 1/A21 etc. That's why I called it "sort of" skew symmetric in the title. What is this type of matrix called and where can I learn about it?

If I did it correctly in the 3x3 version has det = 2 regardless the values of the off diag elements as long as they are non-zero. Obviously the 2x2 version has det= -1.

Answer (score 1):

If the diagonal elements are set to $1$ (rather than $0$) then these are  *multiplicatively antisymmetric* matrices, which are encountered in mathematical texts containing the word "quantum", as a search will demonstrate. A book reference is [An Introduction to Noncommutative Noetherian Rings](https://books.google.com/books?id=vXh1MtvQr_8C)
 by K. R. Goodearl and R. B. Warfield, Jr.

I don't know a name for the object with $0$s on the diagonal, but it's related simply by adding/subtracting the identity matrix, so it might appear in the same field.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you did not do it correctly!  If I understand what you are saying, then the determinant in the three by three case is 
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & a & b \\ \frac{1}{a} & 0 & c \\ \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c} & 0 \end{array}\right|= -a \left|\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{a} & c \\ \frac{1}{b} & 0 \end{array}\right| + b \left|\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{a} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c}\end{array}\right|
= \frac{ac}{b}+ \frac{b}{ac}= \frac{a^2c^2+ b^2}{abc}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks not sure what I did there.. Do you know what this type of matrix is called?